# Changing the required field text on a modelform in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In the docs it says that you use the `Field.error_messages()` function to change the text that is displayed if a field doesn't validate. I don't however find a way to do this for a `modelForm`. I've tried to just do:

```
Field.error_messages={'required': "test"}
```

but that doesn't work, and using it on the field directly just gives an error messages about the field not being defined for some reason even though its defined in the fields variable as

```
fields = ['fieldname']
```

How can you change this text on a model form? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple cases you can specify [custom error messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages) in your `ModelForm` class.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'test'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',...)
```

You could also override the `__init__` of the class.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['first_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'test'}
        ...
```

Comment: Hmm, ok, so i can still explicitly define the form fields in a modelform class.. thanks